# WTForms Set input field after post

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

For below example:

```
Product(form):
   product = TextField('name')
```

If i set this field in GET action

```
form.product.data= "123",
```

render is "123".
However, if i try set this value after POST action,
i allways get value form POST

How can i set this value (rerender) after POST ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted change only particulars  fields,  but rest keep from POST.
I have noticed that data from POST has additional field "raw_data" and set form.product.data fiels hasn't done (re)render. Solution proved to be clear

```
form.product.raw_data = None 
form.product.data = 123
```

render new value
Maybe little bit "elegant" , but works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to clear form data from the form after a user has submitted it?
In that case you could re-initialize the form

when you do

```
product = Product(request.POST)
```

It will fill the data that the user submitted.

```
product = Product()
```

This will clear the data.

Note:
use 4 spaces for every line of the code, so it is displayed well.

Comment: I want to set the input fields from data post

Comment: yea then you would populate it with the post data as i have shown, product = Product(request.POST).

Comment: how you get the post data depends on the framework you are using, above will work for django, for flask you would user request.form